# Firebase Auth for node.js proxy for Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, firebase, firebase-security

The App that I'm working on requires *private*, user file uploads. For upload and download of the files, I'm **proxying Amazon S3 with a node.js server** using the aws-sdk. The client interface is an **Angular Client App**.

I need to authenticate the client user before authorizing file put/get requests. If I'm running a Firebase Node.js client on my server (w/ a secret key), **How can I verify the client on HTTP put/get requests sent from the client to my proxy server?**

For other **Node.js** server tasks, I am using the firebase-work-queue pattern, which can be used to manage the authorization of work-tasks. However, because of proxying S3, I need a way to authenticate the client on my proxy server directly.

Is this type of authentication possible with Simple Login or will it require Custom Login? **Is there a recommended pattern for authenticated proxying with Firebase?**

Thanks for reading.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here @hironroy. If your client has already authenticated against simple login, then why do you need them to auth at the server as well? What does "I need a way to authenticate the client on my proxy server directly" mean?